# Remove all characters from string javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.hourfield').focusout(function() {

    var h;
    var m;
    var timeStr = "";
    var time = "";
    var newFormat = "";

    timeStr = $(this).val();

    //Here I would like to remove all characters which isn't numbers
    timeStr = timeStr.replace("/[^0-9\.]+/g","");

    if(timeStr > 0) {

        h = timeStr.substr(0,2);
        m = timeStr.substr(2,2);

        newFormat = h+':'+m;

        //Add new values
        $(this).val(newFormat);
    }

});
```

[URL to website](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20082618/kalendarium-2/index.html)

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: The regex you wrote, `"/[^0-9\.]+/g"`. You wanted it to be a regex, but you ended up with a string. Lose the quotes and you'll be fine.

Comment: The replace() function doesn't seem to remove the characters if you for example insert "10.00" in the input field. I would like it to remove the dot before reformatting it with the "10:00".

Comment: I've just updated the the code with your suggestion and if you write "10.00" and then click somewhere else you get "10:.0". It should generate "10:00".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified a string to replace by enclosing the regex in quotes. Remove the quotes to specify a Regex.

```
timeStr = timeStr.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hourfield').focusout(function() {

    var h;
    var m;
    var timeStr = "";
    var CleanTimeStr = "";
    var newFormat = "";

    timeStr = $(this).val();
```

> I did some minor changes to the replace() rule and  just 
>   removed the "dots" which was the main purpose

```
    CleanTimeStr = timeStr.replace(/[.]+/g,"");

    if(CleanTimeStr > 0) {

        h = CleanTimeStr.substr(0,2);
        m = CleanTimeStr.substr(2,2);

        newFormat = h+':'+m;

        //Add new values
        $(this).val(newFormat);
    }
});
```

So now it works fine, thanks!